# Listen for Time Zone Changes Even When the App is Closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I am trying to listen for **timezone changes** even when my Android app is **closed**.

### What I tried:

1. I found a intent action for it. It is TIME_ZONE_CHANGED. However it
   is a protected intent that can only sent by system as the
   documentation says and also it probably doesn't allow to make it
   implicit broadcast.
2. I tried AlarmManager, but I couldn't find exact timezone change
   events.
3. I used `schedululeAtFixedRate` in a thread in an app service. It worked perfectly.
   But I don't want it to listen to every hour changes, I want only time zone timezone changes, as I mentioned above.

---

**Edit:**

**MainActivity**

```
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "49";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createNotificationChannel();
    startService(new Intent(this,AppService.class));
}

 private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence c_name = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name);
        String c_desc = getString(R.string.notification_channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,c_name,importance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(c_desc);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <receiver
        android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".AppService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Receiver Class**

```
package com.example.gridview;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Timezone is changed 
    YAY!,executed for "+NOTIFICATION_ID+" times.");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
        sb.append("\n Status: Ok.");
    }
  
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(context,MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentText(sb.toString())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("Hey!");
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
    NOTIFICATION_ID++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You should register a manifest receiver for `"android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"` (AKA [`Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)).  It is one of the [implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) that is not subject to the restrictions on registering manifest receivers in Android 8.0+.

A manifest receiver like this is going to be the only way to detect this type of event when your app is not running.

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution. My receiver class didn't get changes. I am editing question.